# How to make OCR recognize this image

Tags: ocr, tesseract-ocr

original image

[image: 1]

I think recognize the digits from this image would be really easy, but it just can't be recognized by tesseract and a lot of online OCR. Then I process it like this.

process image

[image: 2]

Unfortunately it still can't be recognized by the tesseract.

My tesseract parameter:

```
tesseract input output digits -psm 7
```

That only returns a single dot `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are too small for it to properly work. I took your images and simply scaled them up to a height of 50px (constant resolution) and ran

`tesseract input output -psm 7`

[image: First Images]

My output resulted in

`4 5 3 6 9 8 7 2 1 0`

I did the same with your single 4, and before it got a `.` character as you did. Resized it and it worked fine.

Depending on your circumstances you may need a command line image resizing utility such as [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php) to process them.